# Angular 4 Error: Expected 1 argument found 0

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, syntax-error, angularfire2

I am working on a web application using angular 4 with SB Admin template. I am using firebase with AngularFire 2. Now i am trying to create users permissions to write, delete and read tables from app. I'll leave the code below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";
import {Location} from "@angular/common";
import {UsersService} from "../../../shared/services/users.service";
import {User} from "../../../shared/services/user";
import {AuthService} from "../../../login/auth.service";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    user: User;
    hasProfile = true;
    user_key: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private location: Location,
              private userService: UsersService,
                private authService: AuthService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.subscribe(p => {
          this.userService.getItem(p['key']).subscribe(user => {
              this.user_key = p['key'];
              if (user) {
                  this.user = user;
                  this.hasProfile = true;
              } else {
                  this.user = new User();
              }
          })
      });
  }

    createUserProfile() {
        const data = this.user;
        console.log(data);
        this.userService.createItem(this.user_key, data);
    }

}
```

The problem is at :

```
 ngOnInit() {
          this.route.params.subscribe(p => {
              this.userService.getItem(p['key']).subscribe(user => {
                  this.user_key = p['key'];
                  if (user) {
                      this.user = user;
                      this.hasProfile = true;
                  } else {
                      this.user = new User();
                  }
              })
          });
      }
```

> this.user = new User() Error: Expected 1 argument found 0.

I tried to put it like thie `this.user = new User(1)` and is compiling successfully but the app do not start. Have any of you found in this situation before? Can you explain?

I am not an Angular Expert I'm learning so I might miss something small.

UPDATE: 
Here is the code from User class:

```
export class Roles {
    editor: boolean;
    admin: boolean;
}



export class User {
    $key: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    city: string;
    profile = false;
    admin = false;
    roles: Roles;
    uid: 'string';

constructor(authData) {
    this.name = '';
    this.city = ''
    this.email = authData.email;
    this.roles = { editor: true, admin: false };
}


}
```

Comment: Maybe you should share the code of the `User` class.

Comment: plz share the code of User class

Comment: `import {User} from "../../../shared/services/user";` : your created class has a constructor with one parameter. Try to either remove it, or comply with it.

Comment: @trichetriche This is what he tried, see the one of the last phrases. But he seems to ignore how to use it correctly...

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ How can you say he tried while you don't know what the constructor is taking as a parameter ? It could take `any` and apply the parameter to a string and call `toLowerCase()`, which would compile but would crash the app.

Comment: @trichetriche I can say that because he tried to do something to make it compile but it does not work this is why it crashed. Try does not mean succeed.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ and I said he should comply with the signature, meaning he should provide the correct variable with the correct type, something we both can't know if he tried.

Comment: @trichetriche on that point, i agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

If the `constructor` parameter of `User` class is optional (which is probably, according to your code), then you can modify your constructor as follows :

```
export class User {
  ..............

  constructor(authData?: any) {
     ...........
  }
}
```